# Number of iterations for a simulation without knowing standard deviation

Tags: simulation

Is it possible to determine the number of required iterations of an experiment/simulation to fall within a pre determined confidence interval, without running a default number of simulations to determine mean and standard deviation?

Thinking at the formulas i had seen during my education it was at least required to know the standard deviation to determine the exact confidence interval. I have a simulation model of a production plant with some random variables, where the question is how many iterations are required to fall in that CI without anything being given.

I will require some simulation runs at least to determine the mean and standard deviation correct? Or is it possible by just knowing the desired CI?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Do you really need to know the number of iterations before starting? Can't you at least make a guess after getting a small sample?

Comment: The number of iterations is not known, i was asked to determine the minimum number of iterations. There are roughly 50 different simulations in the model each with a possible number of iterations with simulations looking at different output values. One looks at the number of output products, the other looks at the cycletime change and so on. So i assume a small sample is required to determine certain values for further calculation?

Comment: If the simulated value is a probability, then the largest variance occurs when the value is 1/2, and you can use that as a worst case scenario. More broadly, "ask around"; there may be experience among those in your group about variances or lengths of sim runs that have worked well in the past. If you are entirely on your own to develop such experience, then relatively short trial runs should provide information to get you started.

Comment: Pay attention to geometry and arithmetic. Units matter, if inputs are in units $u,$ then outputs in $u^2$ and $u^3$ can require longer simulation runs. Beware of ratios, especially if the denominator can ever be near 0. Beware of potentially unbounded quantities, such as waiting times, maximums, minimums; some of them may be essentially impossible to simulate. // Try not to insist on unnecessary precision: If it takes $B=100$ iterations to get one reliable significant digit, then (very roughly speaking) it takes $B=10,000$ to get two and a million to get three.